# Can I disable the Magic Mouse swipe to go back feature in Safari?

Tags: safari, mouse

I have an Apple Magic Mouse, and in Safari, when I swipe my fingers left and right on the mouse,  first the page scrolls left or right if there is a horizontal scrollbar, and then if there is no scrollbar or the scrollbar is already at the edge, then Safari will go back/forward in my history.

This is particularly annoying when I am trying to scroll left / right, and accidentally scroll too far and navigate off the page.

For example, if I'm answering / editing a question on StackOverflow which has

```
some really long code block example which is so wide it gets a horizontal scroll bar or the text area has a scroll bar
some really long code block example which is so wide it gets a horizontal scroll bar or the text area has a scroll bar
some really long code block example which is so wide it gets a horizontal scroll bar or the text area has a scroll bar
some really long code block example which is so wide it gets a horizontal scroll bar or the text area has a scroll bar
```

if I quickly swipe left / right to read the code, I often accidentally leave the page I'm on.

Can I disable the "swipe to navigate" back / forward function of Safari? I only want to use swiping to scroll, not to navigate.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Look under "More Gestures" the "Mouse" System Preferences pane:
[image: Screen capture of the "More Gestures" panel]

Set it to two fingers or disable it altogether.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. I swear I looked for this before and couldn't find it! Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to disable this on Safari only?  I like this behavior on all other apps (Preview for example)

Comment: Without a third party app, no. Check out BetterTouchTool it might be able to do this.

Comment: Darn. Its too bad that you have to turn off the feature all together. Its a useful feature for when reading ebooks or pdfs, but an EXTREMELY annoying feature in safari. Anyone know of another solution?

Comment: It's worth clarifying that this solution also works for the same problem in Chrome (and probably other browsers too, although I haven't tested that).

Comment: Thanks sir, you release us from this curse. @AndrewFerrier This also work for FireFox

Comment: Agreed. This behavior is great, except for web browsers, where it should be taken out and shot. I've been using cmd-bracket far too long to need this gesture. All it's good for is discarding forum posts in progress.

Comment: This "feature" has destroyed my work so many times!  It's so sensitive that I don't even realize I made a swiping motion and BOOM everything I typed in on some web site was erased.  Browsing forward again doesn't always bring it back.  Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) is a free solution: it lets you set up multi-touch gestures differently between different applications. I've had no issues using it yet, although I've only been doing so for a few days and only on Lion. It has received a respectable bunch of positive mentions from places like TUAW, MacWorld, and Lifehacker, and the only less-than-great reviews I've been able to find for it seem to be along the general lines of "I wish it also brushed my teeth" and "I turned off $feature and $feature stopped working"

Personally, it has saved my MagicMouse from the ignominy of sharing duty and mousing space with a wired Mighty Mouse.