# How can I turn off "Swipe between pages"?

Tags: macos, system-settings, mouse

I went into system preferences and completely unchecked the swipe between pages button for my magic mouse, but it still does it.  Why won't this feature turn off?  If you're going to tell me my question is a duplicate, please tell me where I can find the answer to this duplicated question because I still have no answer!!!  thank you

Comment: Where do I find these answers?  I've never used this website before.  I just want it fixed without having to pay a computer guy $100 to fix it.  thanx

Comment: Still have no answer to this...  Anyone??  Patrix, mind telling me where I can find the answer since you seem to know my question is a duplicate?  Thanx

Comment: Duplicate questions aren't merged because there's an answer, duplicate questions are merged because there's no use in having multiple questions asking the same one.

Comment: @MistyElam, see if the answer here has some insight for you: [Can I disable the Magic Mouse swipe to go back feature in Safari?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32774/120171)