# Disable Safari from loading previous website when scrolling down with Magic Mouse

Tags: safari, mouse, gesture

How can I stop Safari loading a page from history, each time I scroll the current page over the page end? i.e. swipe upwards on the Magic Mouse when the page is already at the bottom.

This feature is driving me crazy, because reversing the action triggers a reload of the page I was on and which I never intended to leave. Most of the times the page does not resume even close to the state it was in, so I'm losing work in practise every time this happens.

I'm aware of this question [Can I disable the Magic Mouse swipe to go back feature in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32771/can-i-disable-the-magic-mouse-swipe-to-go-back-feature-in-safari), but that deals only with horizontal swipe gestures which I have already disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the Reading List in Safari, and does not occur when viewing webpages normally. Scrolling beyond the end or beginning of a page when viewing it from the Reading List will switch to the next or previous item. This functionality cannot be modified.

Comment: Fantastic! That's it. Easy enough to not load pages from the reading list. Thank you so much!